# Spring boot memory consumption

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a java application with Spring Boot. I have Hibernate, (for mysql connection). I have Paho Mqtt implementation to connect broker and listen some topics, incoming messages inserting database by the listener. Beyond, I have a thread that checks tables if desired condition met, periodically (once a second). Afterall, my applications memory (ram) consumption is ~700-800MB. I wonder is this normal or I did something wrong?

Comment: How do you measure the consumption?

Comment: Im using htop to see which program uses what amount of resources. Maybe it is wrong way, i m not sure.

Comment: You're basically seeing how much memory the Java Virtual Machine has claimed, you're not seeing how much memory the Java application running within it is using. You probably need to research into Java memory management, the **Java heap** to be more specific. I can at this point only guess that what you're seeing is perfectly normal, you'd need to go to work with a profiler such as JVisualVM to be sure.

Comment: You're right about that memory consumption belongs to JVM. I looked vith VisualVM, and my apps seems consumes ~350-400 MB.